# Running plugins in child- from parent-pom in maven

Tags: java, maven, plugins, pom.xml, spotbugs

I want to create a parent pom which over 100 child poms will use it and I want each child using just `maven install` running the plugins from parent, but unfortunately it won't run parent plugins in child plugins.

This is my parent pom and my 2 checkstyle and spotbugs plugins are in it

```
  <build>
<pluginManagement>

  <plugins>

    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${maven.checkstyle.plugin}</version>

      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
          <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
          <version>${maven.puppycrawl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>

      <configuration>
        <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
        <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
        <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
        <violationSeverity>warning</violationSeverity>
      </configuration>

      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>validate</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>check</goal>
          </goals>
          <phase>validate</phase>
        </execution>
      </executions>

    </plugin>

    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
      <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${spotbugs.plugin.version}</version>
      <configuration>
        <threshold>Low</threshold>
        <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
      </configuration>

      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>check</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>

</pluginManagement>
```

and this is in my child pom

```
  <parent>
<groupId>org.parent</groupId>
<artifactId>parent_name</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
</parent>
```

now I want to use `mvn install` or `mvn clean install` to run the child pom and run these two plugins without rewriting them in each child pom, but it doesn't run the plugins.

can anyone tell me what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

remove from **/pluginManagement/plugins** and just put it in **/plugins**.
**/pluginManagement & /dependencyManagement** are merely for defining the configs, for actual usage you need to invoke using **/plugins & /dependencies**.